# Ionic 5 with Angular Header toolbar Auto-expand with Longer Title?

Tags: angular, ionic5

I am trying to build a sign up page for an app in Ionic 5 with Angular. I created a toolbar header with a desired title of "Disaster Relief and Coordination App". But the title is too long to fit on one line of the toolbar header. Is there a way to auto-expand the toolbar down to fit the overflow of the title on another line in the toolbar header?

Here is my current html for the page:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Disaster Relief and Coordination App</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I haven't tried anything with the css yet. Any suggestions to fix this issue would be appreciated.

I have also attached a screenshot of issue I am talking about: [Screenshot of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhz65.png)

Comment: You just don't see professional apps with two-line titles like that. If you really want it you're gonna have to hack it with custom CSS. It will probably make your menu icon look out of place though. I'd recommend a short one line title with supporting text below it in the `<ion-content>` area.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's no way of doing this. The text is presented in a shadow element, if you inspect your DOM in your browser you'll see something like:

```
<ion-title>
  #shadow-root (open)
  <div class="toolbar-title">Disaster Relief and Coordination App</div>
</ion-title>
```

And you can't access your shadow root element directly.

What i've tried:

Adding the following CSS to the page:

```
.toolbar-title {
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: unset;
}
```

Customizing shadow parts using [::part pseudo-selector](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/)

Using `document.querySelector('.toolbar-title')` and changing the CSS directly, inside of the `ngAfterContentInit()` lifecycle hook.

But you can do something different, you can use your on element and CSS to recreate the same title, but wrapping the text.
instead of using the `<ion-title>` try having the following HTML

```
<!-- html template -->
<div class="custom-title">a very long title that must be wraped</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.custom-title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: unset;
  overflow: unset;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: auto;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

This willcreate your own title, you just have to style it to look like a ion-title. But there's a chance that with the default font-size it may cut your text, and there's 2 ways of solving this:

In the `.custom-title` you can set a smaller font-size;

Or you can use the following CSS to make your toolbar bigger:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --min-height: 80px; // here you'll give the height size needed to your toolbar
}
```

If anyone knows a way of changing the shadow DOM CSS please add to my response.